# How to refactor the code to make each of lists in source code sorted?

Tags: python, python-3.x, code-formatting

To be clear, I'm not asking how to sort the lists at runtime. I want to alter the source code.

Essentially I want to refactor the following code with as little effort as possible. I have lots of hardcoded long lists across the codebase, so to sort them manually is tedious,

One option I can think of is to encapsulate all list in code with `Sorted`.

```
t = ["therock","hollywood","rockbottom","inyourhouse"]
Sorted([t])
```

But I am looking for ways to do it without adding addition code cycle, options like running other script or via code editor extension or by any command on top of the codebase to auto-format it.

```
t = ["therock","hollywood","rockbottom","inyourhouse"]
```

should become

```
t = ["hollywood","inyourhouse","rockbottom","therock"]
```

Comment: What do you mean by auto sorting lists in code? Could you show an example of what the code looks like originally, and how you want it to be formatted instead?

Comment: In any case, requests for software recommendations are explicitly off-topic here.

Comment: `t = ["therock","hollywood","rockbottom","inyourhouse"]` should become `t = [
"hollywood","inyourhouse,"rockbottom","therock"]`

Comment: Why not just write `t = sorted(["therock","hollywood","rockbottom","inyourhouse"])`?

Comment: When and where do you want the formatting to happen?

Comment: Not a software reco? You're asking for a pointer to a python code formatter that can do this. I actually doubt there are any, this isn't formatting, it's rewriting.

Comment: @DaveStSomeWhere anywhere formatting option you know should be fine be it some code editor plugin or cli command. Whatever formatting option you know you can tell. Once I have more than one option then I can decide which suits better.

Comment: Adding to @Barmar: It's not just formatting because lists have *order*. Changing that order changes the meaning and behavior of the list, it's not like sorting imports (which absent unusual circumstances shouldn't change behavior).

Comment: @ShadowRanger  sorry for not finding a better word. Yes obviously it's not exactly like formatting imports, at times it changes meaning so technically not a formatting .If it was so simple obviously I would not have asked on stackoverflow.

Comment: What is `isort`? Formatting code is something editors/IDEs do yet you do not mention any specific editor/IDE which renders your question pointless. Different editors have different capabilities activated by different sequences of interactions with keyboard&mouse. We can't really say anymore than this without knowing which editor/IDE you are using. Or are you looking from a program to be run from the command line? Do you want to implement such a program?

Comment: Folks, I do have an on-topic answer, but I am unable to post it because the question was closed so rapidly. I am nominating the question to be re-opened so I can post my answer.

Comment: @MichaelGeary It's been reopened!

Comment: I think without changing the code will be difficult, you will need something that parses the program, recognize hard coded lists and then sort it. Perhaps the easiest is whenever you see a list to be sorted in your code is to add a line with the sort() method, like t.sort()

Answer (score 1):

It may be too late for your problem, but I usually like to write list literals like this:

```
t = [
    'therock',
    'hollywood',
    'rockbottom',
    'inyourhouse'
]
```

I think this makes it a bit easier to distinguish items at a glance, and it also lends itself well to line-based text manipulation in an editor. For example, using vim, I would sort the lines by selecting them in visual mode and using `:sort`.

Comment: yup great answer. To add to your answer, since this is a legacy codebase, to get it in vertical form first I need a formatter which does that , just found that https://github.com/psf/black is  doing that by default , after that your steps. cool man. But to sort all arrays across the entire codebase at once I will have to write script. Let us know if you come across any such script/plugin/cli